# I need add to a array of fields a subfield with geopoint

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, geolocation, logstash

I have an Array of fields like this

```
"varname" ["name1#lat|long",
"name2#lat|long",
"name3#lat|long",
....]
```

I need how to know to get this in filebeat to use in kibana

```
"varname"[ "name1"["location": [lat, long]],
    "name2"["location": [lat, long]],
    "name3"["location": [lat, long]],
    ...]
```

i need to do a subfield into de value array 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create the index mapping with the special structure first and then start to indexing data.

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html